# HTML/CSS: Child element overflows from parent div. How do you make the div all encompassing of the child content?

Tags: css, html, height, overflow

In [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/trusktr/vBSsZ/), you see that the containing div has a red border. However, you also notice that the child spans overlap past the edges of the parent div. Why is this and how can it be fixed so that the containing div encompasses the whole content of the spans?

Answer (score 0):

Changing `line-height` to `22px` for `.entry-utility` seems to do the trick.

**Demo: [jsfiddle.net/7mnP3](http://jsfiddle.net/Marcel/7mnP3/)**

Comment: Thanks, but that means i must have 22px line height, which is what I don't want. There must be some way to make it work!

Comment: @trusktr: ...or just user `overflow:hidden` on the same element, sorted.

Comment: Unfortunately, that will hide some of the edges of the child spans, so that doesn't work. I think there is a solution, I just have no idea what!

Comment: @trusktr: The main reason some of the spans are being truncated is because the `line-height` is so small. Make it a little more taller (say `16px`) and use `overflow:hidden`.

Comment: I figured it out. Check my answer if you're curious.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've isolated the bit of your code you're referring to:

```
<div class="entry-utility">
  <span>
    <h2><a href="#" title="##" rel="bookmark">New Design For Keep Skatin’ Bro</a></h2> 
    Posted in <a href="#" title=" " rel="category tag">Animation</a>, 
    <a href="#" title=" " rel="category tag">Photography</a>, 
    <a href="#" title=" " rel="category tag">Uncategorized</a>, 
    <a href="#" title=" " rel="category tag">Videography</a>, 
    <a href="#" title=" " rel="tag">Joe Pea</a>, 
    <a href="#" rel="tag">Raquel Pea</a>, 
    <a href="#" rel="tag">test</a> on <a href="#">May 27, 2011</a>.
  </span>                                            
</div><!-- .entry-utility -->
```

This is **invalid HTML** as you have an `h2` nested inside a (inline) `span` a span will not contain borders and padding  - but for the sake of showing how this actually affects the CSS display, if you make the `.entry-utility span {display: block;}` that should get the red border containing as you want.. but I think I'd rather fix out the nesting as there is too much forced positioning going on too.

While you have made the `h2` `display: inline;` so it displays like an inline element, you cannot change the nature of the element, it remains a block level element.

Comment: Thanks for that info! I'll go experiment with it and see what I come up with.

Comment: I figured it out. Check my answer if you're curious.